# Reverse a string in Julia

Tags: string, julia, reverse

How to reverse a string in Julia?

I have

```
julia> str = "Hello World!"
```

and I would like str to be reversed. Something like

```
julia> str_reverse = str.reverse
```

str_reverse should be: "!dlroW olleH"

Is there some way to do this without a for-loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `reverse` function:

```
julia> reverse(str)
```

Comment: You may also need to `import Base` and then `Base.reverse()`

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it that looks like Python:

julia> str[end:-1:1]

Comment: Note that this is wrong for unicode strings in Julia.